# Asp Mvc 3 & Ninject - Authorize Attribute + FormsAuthentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, forms-authentication, ninject

I am trying to make a simple scalable web system, and after looking around a bit it seems that forms authentication with cookies is what im looking for, as I do not need a session for storing login related data.

I have recently plumbed in that part of the system and noticed that the authorise attribute was not doing anything. After a look around the internet it seems that Ninject is causing the issue as it doesn't handle the attribute correctly.

Now if this is the case and it doesn't allow me to use the built in authentication mechanism how am I meant to get the same functionality that authorize would normally give me, without having to write my own authentication system?

As currently it looks like I would have to make my own CustomAuthorizationAttribute and then make a filter with that, which I am happy to do, but I cannot find how to get this to defer to the FormsAuthentication mechanism. Also this only seems to work on a controller level, not at an action level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ninject + MVC3 + Authorize attributes with ASP.NET forms authentication using cookies.  Everything works as it should.

What do you mean by "the authorize attribute isn't doing anything?"  Do you have your membership providers set up in your web.config file?

Comment: I read that when using Ninject as a controller factory it cannot use the [Authorize] attribute, so I have just made my own simple cookie reader to mimic it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue just now (that's how I found your question).

After some googling, I tried moving my `IKernel` setup code from `Global.asax` to `App_Start\NInjectMVC3.cs`, and it miraculously worked.

I'm not sure what caused the initial issue though.